# HTTP Streaming with 4g connection

Tags: video-streaming, vpn, http-streaming, 4g

I need to be able to watch a stream being played in a local host port from the web.

The situation:In my raspberry pi, I have a webcam video being streamed to a local port (localhost:8080/mystream), and it is a mjpeg video. I can't use VLC or ffmpeg to stream to a RTMP server since it takes way too much CPU, (even using OMX encoder). This raspberry is embedded in a drone and connected to the internet by a 4g moldem.

I would like to connect directly to this stream from the web ( not on the same network).

My idea is use reverse tunneling or VPN to enable this connection from a public server IP. But I have zero knowledge with VPN nor reverse tunneling. Can someone please guide me through the steps?

Apparently I have to set up a VPN Server somewhere (raspberry pi ? public server?) Then port forward this localhost:port to the public server URL. Finally access the URL to watch the stream? Maybe embed this stream in a website.

I'm really confused =/

I do have access to VPN IPSec from IBM and other Cloud services from them.

Comment: I ended up buying an external encoder that gets the video feed directly from camera via HDMI and encode into a H.264 video stream. Then I get this newly converted stream and use FFMPEG to send it to my Nginx RTMP server.

Answer (score 0):

i would use pivpn on the rpi and ip camviewer to view the stream on my android.
i would connect from phone to pivpn using open vpn